# How to print numbers using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to print natural numbers from 1 to 100 using LINQ and without any loops. The LINQ query I wrote doesn't even compile at all.

```
Console.WriteLine(from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray());
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is wrong on loops? If you have loops, start using functional language.

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't compile it's because you don't have 'select n' at the end. Howeve even if you added it it would just print the name of the type and that is not what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Method syntax:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Query syntax:

```
(from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 100) select n)
    .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Or, if you want a comma separated list:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 100)));
```

This one uses the [String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) overload introduced in .NET 4.0.

Comment: ForEach is part of List, not LINQ.

Comment: The String.Join method doesn't compile as the function expects string[]

Comment: @AbrahamJP .NET 4.0 has some extra overloads, including `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`

Comment: Oh! I was trying your snippets in .NET 3.5, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Your LINQ query is almost near to the solution, only some tweaking is needed.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", (from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 100) select n.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

You can also add ForEach as an extension method to IEnumerable instead of having to convert to list first, if you desire a little better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is imposible to walko over an array without any loops, you can use the ForEach extention method for List class.

```
Enumerable.Range(1,100).ToList().ForEach( i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

I dont know why you would like do this, but the loop might not be writen by you but eventually in some part of code will be presented.

EDIT:
Any solution presented will have somewhere some loop or even two, if you just want to iterate through all elements, you should create an extension where you hide the for each

```
 public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
 {
     if (action == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }

    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but I was looking from the developer point of view to avoid loops.

Comment: It is better to write hide loops, because you cant avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is query language. It can only filter and transform data. That what LINQ is inteded for.
Of course there will be some ForEach extension, but that is not part of LINQ itself.

And just to correct you, there are loops in LINQ, except they are hidden from your sight.